# How to solve this nonlinear partial diffeerential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations

The ordinary differential equation  $u''= (u')^2$ has an special solution $u(x)=-{\rm ln}(x)$, but it seems not easy to solve the generalized partial differential equation
$$
u_{xx}+u_{yy}=(u_{x})^2+(u_{y})^2,
$$
could anyone give some idea?

Comment: $-\ln(xy)$ separates nicely

Answer (score 4):

It is equivalent to $\Delta (e^{-u})=0$, the Poisson equation for $v=e^{-u}$. So at least you get a reduction to a linear DE. Solvability now depends on the boundaries and boundary conditions.